# Code to extract and write data to a particular line using Matlab

Tags: matlab, fwrite, matlab-guide, fread, fclose

I'm currently working on something that requires some help from the experts. I'm new to Matlab. Here is the requirement. I have a large data file (The file can be of any format that best suites the need, say a csv or txt or xlsx files and has mixed content) from which I have to extract the data and write it to a text file after a particular string or a particular line say line No. 15. I have to run this in for loop so that the data extracted from the data file is written to multiple text file that I have already. I developed a code that now extracts the data and write it to text file but it is replacing the contents of the text from the beginning. I want to insert the output (Output has multiple lines) in the specified location. Here is the code that is currently available.

```
fidr = fopen('file1.csv','r') ;

% open file for writing

fidw = fopen('file2.txt','w') ;
% while end of file has not been reached

while ( ~feof(fidr) )

      % read line from reading file

      str = fgets(fidr) ;

% %   %write line to writing file

      fwrite(fidw,str) ;
end
```

Comment: Not really familiar with this topic but from what I can find you might want to use `fopen('file2.csv','a')` to append the data. 5th edits the charm?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Matlab for analyzing bigdata sets of CSV files I recommend you to use [DataStore](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/what-is-a-datastore.html) and also learn how to work with [table](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-table.html)s

Unfortunately for your case `datastore` is only for reading (as far as I know), but you can proceed like this, let's suppose that we have this [csv](http://seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/):

Batting.csv:

```
ds = tabularTextDatastore('Batting.csv');

>> ds.ReadSize = 1

ds = 

  TabularTextDatastore with properties:

                      Files: {
                             '/Users/toni/Documents/MATLAB/Batting.csv'
                             }
               FileEncoding: 'UTF-8'
          ReadVariableNames: true
              VariableNames: {'playerID', 'yearID', 'stint' ... and 19 more}

  Text Format Properties:
             NumHeaderLines: 0
                  Delimiter: ','
               RowDelimiter: '\r\n'
             TreatAsMissing: ''
               MissingValue: NaN

  Advanced Text Format Properties:
            TextscanFormats: {'%q', '%f', '%f' ... and 19 more}
                   TextType: 'char'
         ExponentCharacters: 'eEdD'
               CommentStyle: ''
                 Whitespace: ' \b\t'
    MultipleDelimitersAsOne: false

  Properties that control the table returned by preview, read, readall:
      SelectedVariableNames: {'playerID', 'yearID', 'stint' ... and 19 more}
            SelectedFormats: {'%q', '%f', '%f' ... and 19 more}
                   ReadSize: 1 rows
```

and you can preview the content:

```
>> preview(ds)

ans = 

     playerID      yearID    stint    teamID    lgID    G     AB     R     H     x2B    x3B    HR    RBI    SB    CS    BB    SO    IBB    HBP    SH     SF     GIDP
    ___________    ______    _____    ______    ____    __    ___    __    __    ___    ___    __    ___    __    __    __    __    ___    ___    ___    ___    ____

    'abercda01'    1871      1        'TRO'     'NA'     1      4     0     0     0     0      0      0      0    0      0    0     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'addybo01'     1871      1        'RC1'     'NA'    25    118    30    32     6     0      0     13      8    1      4    0     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'allisar01'    1871      1        'CL1'     'NA'    29    137    28    40     4     5      0     19      3    1      2    5     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'allisdo01'    1871      1        'WS3'     'NA'    27    133    28    44    10     2      2     27      1    1      0    2     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'ansonca01'    1871      1        'RC1'     'NA'    25    120    29    39    11     3      0     16      6    2      2    1     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'armstbo01'    1871      1        'FW1'     'NA'    12     49     9    11     2     1      0      5      0    1      0    1     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'barkeal01'    1871      1        'RC1'     'NA'     1      4     0     1     0     0      0      2      0    0      1    0     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'barnero01'    1871      1        'BS1'     'NA'    31    157    66    63    10     9      0     34     11
```

working with the datatable:

```
>> reset(ds)
>> while hasdata(ds)
T = read(ds);
disp(T(strcmp(T.teamID,'RC1'),:));
end
     playerID      yearID    stint    teamID    lgID    G     AB     R     H     x2B    x3B    HR    RBI    SB    CS    BB    SO    IBB    HBP    SH     SF     GIDP
    ___________    ______    _____    ______    ____    __    ___    __    __    ___    ___    __    ___    __    __    __    __    ___    ___    ___    ___    ____

    'addybo01'     1871      1        'RC1'     'NA'    25    118    30    32     6     0      0     13      8    1     4     0     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'ansonca01'    1871      1        'RC1'     'NA'    25    120    29    39    11     3      0     16      6    2     2     1     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'barkeal01'    1871      1        'RC1'     'NA'     1      4     0     1     0     0      0      2      0    0     1     0     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'birdge01'     1871      1        'RC1'     'NA'    25    106    19    28     2     5      0     13      1    0     3     2     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'fishech01'    1871      1        'RC1'     'NA'    25    123    24    28     3     3      1     22      1    2     3     1     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'fulmech01'    1871      1        'RC1'     'NA'    16     63    11    17     1     3      0      3      0    0     5     1     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'hamra01'      1871      1        'RC1'     'NA'    25    113    25    28     4     0      0     12      6    2     1     7     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'hastisc01'    1871      1        'RC1'     'NA'    25    118    27    30     6     4      0     20     11    2     2     4     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'mackde01'     1871      1        'RC1'     'NA'    25    122    34    30     7     1      0     17     12    0     8     7     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'sagerpo01'    1871      1        'RC1'     'NA'     8     39     9    11     0     0      0      5      5    1     2     2     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN 
    'stirega01'    1871      1        'RC1'     'NA'    25    110    23    30     4     6      2     24      3    0     7     5     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

and finally a dirty way of getting your work:

```
>> reset(ds)
>> T = readall(ds);
>> writetable(T(strcmp(T.teamID,'RC1'),:),'mydata.txt');
```

getting a file called mydata.txt

with this content:

```
playerID,yearID,stint,teamID,lgID,G,AB,R,H,x2B,x3B,HR,RBI,SB,CS,BB,SO,IBB,HBP,SH,SF,GIDP
addybo01,1871,1,RC1,NA,25,118,30,32,6,0,0,13,8,1,4,0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
ansonca01,1871,1,RC1,NA,25,120,29,39,11,3,0,16,6,2,2,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
barkeal01,1871,1,RC1,NA,1,4,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
birdge01,1871,1,RC1,NA,25,106,19,28,2,5,0,13,1,0,3,2,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
fishech01,1871,1,RC1,NA,25,123,24,28,3,3,1,22,1,2,3,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
fulmech01,1871,1,RC1,NA,16,63,11,17,1,3,0,3,0,0,5,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
hamra01,1871,1,RC1,NA,25,113,25,28,4,0,0,12,6,2,1,7,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
hastisc01,1871,1,RC1,NA,25,118,27,30,6,4,0,20,11,2,2,4,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
mackde01,1871,1,RC1,NA,25,122,34,30,7,1,0,17,12,0,8,7,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
sagerpo01,1871,1,RC1,NA,8,39,9,11,0,0,0,5,5,1,2,2,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
stirega01,1871,1,RC1,NA,25,110,23,30,4,6,2,24,3,0,7,5,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I will have a look at the datastore and will try your code. But still there is no way for storing the data to the particular location in the text file (mydata.txt file as illustrated by you). The above code provided by me works fine to write the data to the text file. But how to write those data to the particular line. Any help is appreciated. Thank you once again.